# How to compare the password from php

Tags: php, encryption

I used a library in Android for cryptare password and enter it into the database. Now creating a php page I would like to compare the password with the one but do not know how to do because they do not know how to encrypt it before comparing.

In java code i use this for crypt with this library (https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption):

```
final String key = "my_secret";
final String salt = "my_secret";
final byte[] iv = new byte[16];
```

I have tried this but dont work

```
    <?php

class MCrypt {

    private $hex_iv = '0000000000000000'; # converted JAVA byte code in to HEX and placed it here               
    private $key = 'my_secret'; #Same as in JAVA

    function __construct() {
        $this->key = hash('sha256', $this->key, true);
    }

    function encrypt($str) {       
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $this->hexToStr($this->hex_iv));
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
        $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);        
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }

    function decrypt($code) {        
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $this->hexToStr($this->hex_iv));
        $str = mdecrypt_generic($td, base64_decode($code));
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);        
        return $this->strippadding($str);               
    }

    /*
      For PKCS7 padding
     */

    private function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 16) {
        $len = strlen($string);
        $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
        $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        return $string;
    }

    private function strippadding($string) {
        $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
        $slastc = chr($slast);
        $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
        if (preg_match("/$slastc{" . $slast . "}/", $string)) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - $slast);
            return $string;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
}

$encryption = new MCrypt();
echo $encryption->encrypt('asd') . "<br/>";
?>
```

Please help me, I can not go on with my project if I can not compare the password :(

Answer (score 2):

**Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets admin access he will also get the encryption key.

Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions.

The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

For more information see:

1. [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton.
2. [DRAFT NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Authentication Guideline](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)
3. [NIST’s new password rules – what you need to know](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/08/18/nists-new-password-rules-what-you-need-to-know/) by Sophos
4. [How to store your users’ passwords safely](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) by Sophos

Comment: Sorry buy i crypt the password with my own key in java application and when the user insert for example "abc" library encrypt this and comprare in database mysql if equals open app... I want implement this in php but i cant crypt password and compare with row password.. i have 500 users use my app. and i want open my website with same credentials.

Comment: Encrypting passwords is not a secure method. You need to update to a current iterated hashing method and update the existing accounts. Keep in mind that many of your users may be using the same or similar logins on sensitive systems, a bad idea but it is common. Thus an attacker of your system can gain information allowing attacks on your users other systems. You will most likely not know your system has been attacked. Please see the updated answer for more information.

Comment: @user7478568 If you have 500 people using your app then you should probably be a bit more concerned about the security issues that zaph has outlined above.  It looks like you've just ignored them!  What you are doing is **fundamentally insecure** and should be changed before you do anything else.